# Access 2016 parameter value message displayed when selecting value from a 2nd sub form combo box

Tags: forms, combobox, ms-access-2016, subform

I have an Access 2016 database with a timesheet form.  I've been asked to modify the sub form so the values in the "Work Description" combo box are based on the selection in the "Contract_ID" combobox.

The "Contract_ID" combo box runs uses the following SQL in the Row Source property to display all of the available options:

```
SELECT Contract.ContractID, Contract.[Contract Name], Contract.Active FROM Contract WHERE (((Contract.Active)=Yes)) ORDER BY Contract.[Contract Name];
```

The "Contract Name" is the value displayed in the "Contract_ID" combo box and selected by the user.

When I add the following SQL to the Row Source property for the "Work_Description" combo box, I get the appropriate values for the appropriate selections in the "Contract_ID combo box.  As is I get the same values and not the ones associated with each "Contract Name" / "Contract ID".

```
SELECT [Work Descriptions].[Work Desc ID], [Work Descriptions].[Work Description], Contract.ContractID
FROM Contract INNER JOIN [Work Descriptions] ON Contract.ContractID = [Work Descriptions].[Contract ID]
WHERE (((Contract.ContractID)=2308));
```

I'm trying to modify "2308" so the SQL in the Work_Description Row Source property uses the "ContractID" from the "Contract_ID combo box (and not the "Contract Name").

I found some examples and I tried to replace "2308" with:

```
[Forms]![Timesheet Subform]![Contract ID]![ContractID]
[Forms]![Timesheet Subform]![Contract ID]
[Forms]![Contract ID]![ContractID]
```

When I try to make a selection on the "Work_Description" combo box, I'm getting an "Enter Parameter Value" message that displays whatever string I used to replace 2308.

I'm fairly certain it is a syntax issue but can't find the correct solution to my issue.  Following is information about the form and sub form:

```
Form Name:      "Timesheet"
Sub Form Name:  "Timesheet Subform"
1st Combo box:  "Contract_ID"
2
```

nd Combo box:  "Work_Description"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for taking the time to review this message....

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
[Forms]![Timesheet]![NameOfTimesheetSubformCONTROL].Form![Work_Description]
```